# Can someone explain what is the best way to share an URL that can keep track of the Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm having hard times understanding how I can keep the current state when sharing an URL.

I have an app made with React and Redux.

1. When I click on a button I'm dispatching an action to update the store and I'm changing the route at the same time.
2. The Redux store gets updated and the component gets rendered with data from the Redux store.
3. If I want to share the URL to a person that has the same app, that person does not have the store updated so it wont render anything.

I tried to summarize the code:

```
on route: /
  <Home>
    <BookList data={featured} />
    <BookList data={top} />
  </Home>

on route: /record/:recid
  <BookDetails>
    <BookInfo />
    <BookList data={suggested}/>
  </BookDetails>    

BookList is a reusable component:
<BookList>
  <BookItem onCLick={goToDetailsPage}/>
  <BookItem />
  <BookItem />
  <BookItem />
</BookList>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you for all the help you can provide!

Comment: How are you fetching the data? Through a form submission or from a URL parameter? Adding some code would help us out answer this question.

Comment: watch this! https://youtu.be/brCGZ8Lk-HY

Comment: Do you have any persistent storage logic? Or are just working with React-Redux only?

Comment: I cannot add code. I'm sorry. Basically it's a library and you have multiple books displayed on the home page. The moment you click a book I'm fetching data (book details) from an API and save it to `currentBook`. The problem is when I share the URL this action is not done on the other machine and you wont see a `currentBook` because no action was triggered.

Comment: Which type of solution did you have in mind if, according to my understanding, you cannot add code? You would most certainly have to update either some route logic, the componentDidMount method, or a url param of sorts - but all those require code changes by the sound of it.

Comment: One solution was, as you were saying, is that I was triggering the action not when I was clicking the button on the homepage but in the component itself in  `componentDidMount` but I've read a couple of articles and none recommends to dispatch actions in the lifecycle methods, they say and I'm quoting: "It's evil" and I was trying to think of another solution, a better one.

Comment: I'm assuming you can edit the code of your front end application then?

Comment: Yes, I can edit the code.

Comment: Assuming your routes are home `/` and some book `/:bookId` your container component for the `/:bookId` route should have a fetch mechanism in `componentDidMount` for a book model.This is where React docs recommend you place data fetching logic. Dispatching a fetch action from here is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was doing. I had `/record/:recid` and I was fetching it in `componentDidMount`, but I encountered another problem here, below I had a suggested books and when you where clicking on a suggested book the url was changing but the component was not, and it's normal because the component was already mounted (the `BookDetails` component).

Comment: @FranCarstens thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Have you looked at adding `withRouter()` from react-router? Docs here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md. If that doesn't work, let's chat.

Comment: This conversation goes on like that forever. It is better to update your question with some code.

Comment: @devserkan I will try to add some code

Answer (score 2):

In order to load the correct state to your model view (book), you'll need to have access to the necessary variables. Two simple ways to achieve this is through a url param `?recid=12` or using react-router's match params, which you're doing here. You have access to the `:recid` through the route `match.params.recid`.

React docs recommend fetching data in `componentDidMount()`, but there's nothing wrong with fetching new data in `componentDidUpdate()` when your path updates. Remember to keep track of your fetching state, so you don't make multiple api calls. A watered down version could look something like this:

```
class BookModel extends Component {
  constructor {...}

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, match } = this.props;
    const { recid } = match.params;

    dispatch(someFetchAction("book", recid));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { dispatch, fetching, match } = this.props;
    const oldBook = prevProps.match.params.recid;
    const newBook = match.params.recid;
    const didUpdate = oldBook !== newBook;

    //fetch new record if not already fetching and record id has changed
    !fetching && didUpdate && dispatch(someFetchAction("book", newBook));
  }

  render() {...}
}

export default connect((store, props) => ({
  bookModels: store.bookModels,
  fetching: store.fetching
}))(BookModel);
```

If you're experiencing issues with updates not happening, you may want to add [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md), but I don't believe it would be necessary in this case.